# how to add greek letters to nomnoml diagram in R

Tags: javascript, r, nomnoml

I am using the `nomnoml` package to create diagrams in combination with `rmarkdown`. How can I add greek letters to my arrows?

I have naively tried the following

````
---
title: "Nomnoml Diagram"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(nomnoml)
```

```{nomnoml, svg=TRUE}
[a]-> \alpha [b]
[c]-> \u03be [d]
```
````

Both do not work.

Comment: You should embed that code chunk in a complete document, so others can try it out.

Comment: Example should now be fully reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to use Unicode escapes in the source, you will have to use an R code chunk instead of a nomnoml code chunk.  For example,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(nomnoml)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
nomnoml("[a]->\u03B1[b]", svg = TRUE)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

It works if you just paste `α` into RStudio, like this:

````
```{nomnoml, svg=TRUE}
[a]->α[b]
```
````

If you don't find `α` on your keyboard you can write `"\u03B1"` in the console and copy the output.

#### Full working document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(nomnoml)
```

```{nomnoml, svg=TRUE}
[a]->α[b]
```
````

Comment: Any ideas how to add "\u03B1" directly without going via the console?